# Count the number of nodes with the same name in a tree

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying count the number of nodes with the same name in a tree, but having difficulty. This is what I've tried:

```
musics = {'genre':'music', 'children':[{'genre':'Pop', 'children':[{'genre':'Eurobeat','children':[]},
                                                           {'genre':'Austropop','children':[]},
                                                           {'genre':'hard rock', 'children':[]}]},
                               {'genre':'Latin', 'children':[{'genre':'Eurobeat', 'children':[{'genre':'Chicha', 'children':[{'genre':'Eurobeat','children':[]}]}]},
                                                           {'genre':'Bachata', 'children':[]}, {'genre':'Criolla', 'children':[]}]}]}


class MUsicNode(object):
    def __init__(self, genre):
        self.genre = genre
        self.children = []

    def add(self,x):
        self.children.append(x)

    def count_name(self,genre):
        name_count = 0
        for node in self.children:
            if node.genre == genre:
                print "same genre"
                print "word = ", genre
                name_count+=1
            node.count_name(genre)
        return name_count



def create_tree(musics):
    for key,value in musics.items():
        if key == 'genre':
            node = value  
            var = MUsicNode(node)
        if key == 'children':
            kid = value

    for n in kid:
        var.add(create_tree(n))
    return var


Tree = create_tree(musics)

print Tree.count_name('Eurobeat'), "<---COUNT FOR NAME 'Eurobeat' "
```

"Eurobeat" must be 3, but my output is:

```
same genre

word =  Eurobeat

same genre

word =  Eurobeat

same genre

word =  Eurobeat

0 <---COUNT FOR NAME 'Eurobeat'
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `name_count += node.count_name(genre)` in `count_name()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `name_count` to be a function parameter so you could set a default value of 0 and pass in your current count for your recursive call:

```
def count_name(self,genre,name_count = 0):

    for node in self.children:
        if node.genre == genre:
            print ("same genre") #you probably know this but take this
            print ("word = ", genre) #and this line out to only print `3`
            name_count+=1
        name_count = node.count_name(genre,name_count)
    return name_count
```

this will yield:

```
>>> musics = {'genre':'music', 'children':[{'genre':'Pop', 'children':[{'genre':'Eurobeat','children':[]},
                                                           {'genre':'Austropop','children':[]},
                                                           {'genre':'hard rock', 'children':[]}]},
                               {'genre':'Latin', 'children':[{'genre':'Eurobeat', 'children':[{'genre':'Chicha', 'children':[{'genre':'Eurobeat','children':[]}]}]},
                                                           {'genre':'Bachata', 'children':[]}, {'genre':'Criolla', 'children':[]}]}]}

>>> tree = create_tree(musics)
>>> tree.count_name('Eurobeat')
same genre
word =  Eurobeat
same genre
word =  Eurobeat
same genre
word =  Eurobeat
3
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the recursive step. Or better, you have it (`node.count_name(genre)`) but you do not use its result, so it's like you don't do it at all!

You should "catch" the result of the recursive call and use it to make the "general" result. I won't tell you how in order to not spoil the fun but it's pretty easy.

Or, maybe, you didn't forget it but you thought that the recursive call could see and operate on the `name_count` variable defined in the parent call, so basically a [static variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable). In python, there isn't a direct equivalent of the static variables of, for example, C. Every local variable is [automatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) and therefore reset at each call, even if the call comes from the same function.